# ¿Cómo se llama a la Técnica de Importación de varios Íconos mediante un solo LInk? (Ej: Font Awesome)

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, frontend

He visto como en vez de colocar imagen por imagen (obviamente con sus respectivos directorios), simplemente establecían en el head un Link y en la parte de las listas (en donde van a importar las imagenes) agregan la etiqueta , logrando así importar varios íconos de manera sorprendente.
Ejemplo:

```
   <!-- Font Awesome Cdn Link -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" />
    <!-- Aquí utilizan la etiqueta i para importar los íconos -->
<ul>
          <li><a href="#">
            **<i class="fas fa-user"></i>**
            <span class="nav-item">Dashboard</span>
          </a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">
            **<i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i>**
            <span class="nav-item">Analytics</span>
          </a>
          </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Lo que hacen es crear una tipografía (fuente) que en lugar de tener letras tienen iconos. Esta técnica es muy útil porque te permite aumentar el tamaño del icono cambiando el `font-size` sin pixelearse y además te permite cambiar el color

Comment: Cuando se utliza una image con múltiples imágenes dentro (_NO sería el caso de FontAwesome_), la técnica se llama crear un [`spirte`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_images/Implementing_image_sprites_in_CSS)

Answer (score 0):

Se le conoce simplemente como "importar librería", en tu caso para los iconos, sería "importar librería de iconos". Esta técnica te permite utilizar una única solicitud de enlace para cargar una fuente que contiene múltiples íconos.

En el ejemplo que brindad de Font Awesome, es correcto, apenas coloques el enlace para importar la librería, ya puedes usar los iconos que deseas mediante las etiquetas y nombres de clases que te da la documentación de la página.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Aquí puedes utilizar los íconos de Font Awesome -->
  <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
  <!-- ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS!

Answer (score 0):

En el ejemplo que pones, el *link* en el *head* está creando una especie de fantasía, pero no hay tal cosa.

El link simplemente asocia a un archivo CSS que carga una tipografía, un *tipo de letra*, (*font face* en inglés) con el CSS `@font-face` y luego crea una serie de clases que, en realidad, agregan un único caracter unicode al inicio del texto que pueda incluir el elemento al que se asocie dicha clase.

Esto, porque [Unicode tiene soporte para *emotíconos* o *emojis*](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) y los archivos de tipo de letra de font-awesome incluyen algunos de estos emotíconos o emojis.

Puedes lograr usar estos simplemente añadiendo los caracteres al texto, siempre que utilices una tipografía que los incluya, se van a mostrar en pantalla.

He preparado un ejemplo mínimo para demostrarlo, utilizando la misma fuente que enlazas en la pregunta, pero esta vez sin el *link mágico*, sino directamente en el CSS del snippet a continuación.

He preparado dos clases, una que utiliza el *font-awesome* con un espesor de 900 y otra el *font-awesome* con un espesor de 400.

Luego, añado caracteres unicode al texto, que muestran los *íconos* que tu añades usando clases, algunos otros de font-awesome y algunos otros emojis comunes, en tres divs que muestran con font awesome de ambos espesores y luego sin font-awesome, para que puedas comparar el resultado.

Tip: Los caracteres unicode se añaden con `&#código;`, dónde el código se puede escribir en decimal o en hexadecimal prefijándolo con una `x`.

Observa que no todas las tipografías tienen soporte para todos los caracteres utilizados en mi ejemplo:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: block;
  src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot");
  src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2") format("woff2"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff") format("woff"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/webfonts/fa-regular-400.ttf") format("truetype"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/webfonts/fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); 
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-display: block;
  src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot");
  src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2") format("woff2"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff") format("woff"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf") format("truetype"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/webfonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); 
}

.awesome900 {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.awesome400 {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="awesome900">
    <h2>Con font-awesome weight 900</h2>
    <p>Hola, esto es el <i>fa-user</i>: &#xf007;</p>
    <p>Y esto es el <i>fa-chart-bar</i> &#xf080;</p>
    <p>Otros íconos especiales de font-awesome: &#xf406; &#xf4fb; &#xf4fd; &#xf500;</p>
    <p>Otros emojis comunes: &#x1f600; &#x1f603; &#x1f60e; &#x1f648; &#x1f918; &#x1f4aa; &#x1f440; &#128003; &#128019; </p>
  </div>
  <div class="awesome400">
    <h2>Con font-awesome weight 400</h2>
    <p>Hola, esto es el <i>fa-user</i>: &#xf007;</p>
    <p>Y esto es el <i>fa-chart-bar</i> &#xf080;</p>
    <p>Otros íconos especiales de font-awesome: &#xf406; &#xf4fb; &#xf4fd; &#xf500;</p>
    <p>Otros emojis comunes: &#x1f600; &#x1f603; &#x1f60e; &#x1f648; &#x1f918; &#x1f4aa; &#x1f440; &#128003; &#128019; </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Sin font-awesome</h2>
    <p>Hola, esto es el <i>fa-user</i>: &#xf007;</p>
    <p>Y esto es el <i>fa-chart-bar</i> &#xf080;</p>
    <p>Otros íconos especiales de font-awesome: &#xf406; &#xf4fb; &#xf4fd; &#xf500;</p>
    <p>Otros emojis comunes: &#x1f600; &#x1f603; &#x1f60e; &#x1f648; &#x1f918; &#x1f4aa; &#x1f440; &#128003; &#128019; </p>
  </div>
<body>
```

Para finalizar, puedes preparar tu mismo archivos CSS que contengan todo lo necesario para cargar otras tipografías y luego hacer uso de ellas en tus páginas, incluyendo emojis, si los soportan.

Te puede resultar interesante también estudiar la [versión no *minificada* del archivo CSS que importas](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.css) en tu ejemplo.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS!